# How to filter out rows by a set of names you already have?

Tags: r, filter, tibble

I have a tibble similar to:

```
tibble(
x = c("christmas", "christmas", "car", "dog")
y = c("one","two","three", "four")
)
```

and then I have another tibble like:

```
tibble(
x = c("christmas", "dog")
)
```

Notice the two christmas' that are in the first tibble.
I want to use the second tibble's column to output new columns from the first:

```
tibble(
x = c("christmas","christmas", "dog")
y = c("one","two","four")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `base R` solution using `%in%` and indexing:

```
#Code
df1[df1$x %in% df2$x,]
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x         y    
  <chr>     <chr>
1 christmas one  
2 christmas two  
3 dog       four
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(x = c("christmas", "christmas", "car", "dog"), 
    y = c("one", "two", "three", "four")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(x = c("christmas", "dog")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with SQL terminology:

```
library(dplyr)
> df1 %>% inner_join(df2)
Joining, by = "x"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x         y    
  <chr>     <chr>
1 christmas one  
2 christmas two  
3 dog       four 
>
```

Using base R

```
> merge(df1, df2)
          x    y
1 christmas  one
2 christmas  two
3       dog four
>
```